# How to force checkboxGroupInput elements inside a box

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a reactive `checkboxGroupInput` taking as values the column names from a user-uploaded inputfile. The input file can sometimes have more than a hundred columns, so I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33108619/7306168) answer to align the choices into multiple columns. It works nicely most of the time, but sometimes the column names are very large, so the labels fall outside the box:

[image]

Any idea how can I overcome this issue?

I have prepared a sample code using `mtcars` dataset (and `row.names` instead of `colnames` just for the sake of the example).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    busyIndicator(text="Loading..."),
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML('
             .multicol { 
             -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
             -moz-column-count: 3;    /* Firefox */ 
             column-count: 3; 
             -moz-column-fill: auto;
             -column-fill: auto;
             }
             ')
        )
        ),  

    menuItem("Plot result", tabName = "scatterplot", icon = icon("area-chart"))
    )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "scatterplot", 
              box(
                title="CHECKBOX",solidHeader = TRUE, status="primary",
                tags$div(align = 'left', 
                         class = 'multicol', uiOutput("covarselect")),
                width=2
              )
            )
    )
)

ui=dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "analysis"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$covarselect <- renderUI({
    mtcars <- datasets::mtcars
    row.names(mtcars) <- gsub(" ","",row.names(mtcars))
    checkboxGroupInput("carselect","Select any that apply",as.list(row.names(mtcars)),inline=F)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT**

As per the suggestion of Nikhil Nanjappa I have tried reproducing the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bea19/5Lfo8em1/), although I did not succeed in reproducing the `box` as in `shinydashboard`

Comment: This seems an HTML + CSS issue, can you post them as well here. Maybe create a Fiddle with the generated HTML.

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil I am not familiar with html coding in general, but I have tried presenting the code in a fiddle (added it to my OP)

Comment: You need to look into adding a column break - Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314726/css-multi-column-layout-of-list-items-doesnt-align-properly-in-chrome) but adding instead, not avoiding

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-y` and `height` style attributes, where the grouped checkboxes are inside a division `<div>`, this is similar to your design.

```
UI:

fluidRow(
 box(
     width = 2,
     title = "Grouped Checkboxes",
     div(id = 'groupchk' style = 'height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;', 
         checkboxGroupInput("chkbxgrp", "Choose:", choices = many_choices)
    )
),
```

Furthermore, let's say the grouped checkbox is next to a `box` with a plot in your `fluidRow`. You'd like to match the relative height of the plot. You would remove the style from your division `groupchk`, and we can set the height dynamically with `shinyjs::runjs` function.

Do this on some reactive, observe, or renderUI function:

First obtain the height of the element you want to match, then assign it and set the overflow-y as well. To make shinyjs work, you must `useShinyjs()`  [shinyjs::](https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/basic)

```
SERVER:

runjs("var newHeight = $('#plot').height(); 
       $('#groupchk').height(newHeight); 
       $('#groupchk').css('overflow-y','scroll')")
```